# Can I run Micro Cloud with edited Java version, or JVM?

Tags: java

Is it possible to run Micro cloud Foundry on new (self edited) java version?
I have enhanced few core Java classes to support Taint Tracking, this has been done for Academic purposes only, so it is not breaking Sun t&c's.
Specifically I need to run Micro cloud on new Java version, so that I can launch web applications on it and test the taint tracking propagation on enhanced core java classes.

*Taint tracking: enhanced core java classes such as String, String builder etc. to have extra boolean value which identifies whether the input is trusted or not. (SQL injections, XSS etc.)

Kind regards,
Assel

Comment: Have you tried?  What makes you think it might not be possible?